# separate nameservers for each zone?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone, amazon-route53, domain-name

From this [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zone-public-considerations.html), and bunch of other resources and stuff
I came to know that for aws route53, each hosted zone has different set of nameservers called as delegation sets.

My question is apart from AWS, in normal scenarios, do every domain in the world has separate set of dns servers, of course they won't be physical, kind of virtual, but is this true for all the domains?

Like I recently bought a domain from hostinger, and it comes with a set of nameservers associated with my domain.

**Are they specific to me only?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an implementation detail of the way each specific DNS hosting provider runs their systems.

Most smaller providers configure all their servers identically, as a single pool that hosts all zones. At some point they become large enough that they have to split the customers and their zones into smaller groups so that all the zones would be easier to fit, with e.g. server pool A hosting zones for customer group A, or something along those lines. Some providers might even use customer-specific names for the same nameservers, so that it would be easier to split them in the future.

The only universal answer is that if the DNS hosting provider tells you that you should use nameservers X and Y, then those are the nameservers that you should use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the text with corrected grammar and a few structural adjustments:

It's important to understand DNS architecture. You can visualize it as a tree. At the top, you have the Root Servers, consisting of 13 servers (labeled a to m). [You can see the list here](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/servers).

Below the Root Servers, you'll find two types of Top Level Domains (TLDs): generic TLDs (gTLDs) and country-code TLDs (ccTLDs). Multiple organizations host DNS servers for these TLDs.

When you buy a domain, for example, example.uk, you request the organization that hosts the .UK TLD to point to your DNS servers. Different providers, like AWS, have DNS servers hosting multiple DNS Zones, so the IPs will vary depending on where you host your Authoritative DNS Server.

It's important to note that a single DNS server can host multiple Zones. For instance, GoDaddy uses a share server(s) to host multiple domains. Essentially, you can use a set of servers for a single domain or multiple domains, depending on your provider's architecture.
[image]